# Unable to sniff on interface eth2 using sockets with Python 3.7

Tags: python, linux, sockets, centos

I am trying to sniff traffic on a server that has an interface (eth2) that all network traffic is going across.

I can get the sniffer to work on eth0 but when I set the script to listen on eth2, I only get traffic from eth0. I know this because the source IP of the packets I receive are for eth0. I have verified that the right traffic is coming across eth2 via tcpdump.

Here is where I am setting the interface to eth2.

```
import socket
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))
conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE, str("eth2" + '\0').encode('utf-8'))
```

Any ideas on why I only get eth0 traffic?

Comment: What does `socket.ntohs(3)` return, and which adapter is associated with it? Does the adapter support promiscuous mode?

Comment: Yes, the interface supports promiscuous mode as tcpdump works on it.  When I print out socket.ntohs(3), I get 768.  How do I relate that number to an interface?

Comment: More investigation on ntohs, network to host short.  This number (3) says to capture all packets.  From what I can tell it has nothing to do with which interface.